# Conditional MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with columns: conditional1, conditional2, data. I need to return all the rows where conditional1 = value1 if any of those rows also contains conditional2 = value2. How can I do this?

Edit: There's some confusion about what I'm asking.

If you have columns

`conditional1 | conditional2 | data

A | A | A

A | B | A`

I want to return both rows if conditional1 = A and conditional2 = B

Edit 2: There's still some confusion.

Here is another example:

conditional1 | conditional2 | data

1 | 1 | A

1 | 2 | B

2 | 1 | C

2 | 2 | D

If conditional1 = 1 and conditional2 = 1, it should return

1 | 1 | A

1 | 2 | B

If conditional1 = 2 and conditional2 = 1, it should return

2 | 1 | C

2 | 2 | D

If conditional1 = 2 and conditional2 = 2, it should return

2 | 1 | C

2 | 2 | D

If conditional1 = 2 and conditional2 = 3, it should return no rows.

Comment: Are you stuck with the query itself, or implementing this in PHP, or ?

Comment: I edited the question because there was some confusion.

Comment: You question still makes no sense. (Perhaps that's why *all* of the existing answers are incorrect.) Do you mean if conditional1 = A **OR** conditional2 = B?

Comment: you didn't clarified. mark baker answered this question as it is

Comment: What condition determines whether you return the first row? With your edit, this is very unclear... what links the first row to the second to say that it should be returned even though conditional2 is not 'B'?

Comment: middaparka: No. In the example, all rows where conditional1 = A are returned, but only if conditional2 = B for some row where conditional1 = A. The current answers below would only return where both conditionals are true, which is one row and not two.

Comment: You newest example wasn't very good... maybe you should have used different letters in the third column to help quickly differentiate the difference for your new cases

Comment: I modified the example accordingly. I can make another example if that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from tbl A
where conditional1 = 'A'
and exists (
  select * from tbl B
  where B.conditional1 = 'A' and B.conditional2 = 'B')
```

or a more MySQL friendly version

```
select * from tbl
where conditional1 in
(
    select conditional1 
    from tbl
    where conditional1 = 'A' and conditional2 = 'B'
)
```

Comment: I tried your second version, but I'm getting syntax errors with it:select * from table
where conditional1 in
(
    select conditional1 
    from table
    where conditional1 = 1 and conditional2 = 1
)

Comment: If you're using the literal "table", then that's obviously wrong. Otherwise I syntax checked in MySQL and SQL Server at least, both are fine with it

Comment: You're right -- using "table" in the example was not the smartest thing to do. Your answer works great. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's a MySQL friendly answer? I thought MySQL [had big problems with subqueries contained in `in`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql/3417190#3417190)? i.e. that it re-evaluates the sub query for each row in the outer query.

Comment: @Martin / comparing the two, the IN clause can only ever return one value for conditional1 (I could have made it 'A'). The first one uses EXISTS, which has some weird optimization (I know because it performs worse than LEFT JOIN + IS NULL) - so I took the safer route..

Comment: Ah I see. I think `=` and `DISTINCT` still might perform better than `IN` from [this OP's experience](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416076/this-select-query-takes-180-seconds-to-finish)?

Comment: @Martin / ok got you now. I should have used '='. But this is a very simple query, so the bug won't bite? I tend to leave unedited answers alone, since it looks .. clean :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE conditional1 = 'A' AND 1 IN 
        ( SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE conditional1 = 'A' AND conditional2 = 'B' LIMIT 1 )
```

I think I finally understand!

Comment: Sorry, there's a problem on my end: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'